# How do I use Option::or with references to Options?

Tags: rust, reference, option-type

I have the following:

```
fn foo(f: &Option<Huge>) {}

fn bar(a: &Option<Huge>, b: &Option<Huge>) {
    foo(a.or(b));
}
```

`Huge` is some big struct that I don't want to copy or clone. This does not work because `.or()` takes `a` and `b` by value.

Is there an easy solution? I can probably do something like this:

```
foo(if a.is_some() { a } else { b });
```

Surely there is a better way?

Comment: Have you tried `as_ref()`? It allows one to go from `&Option<T>` to `Option<&T>`.

Comment: Like `foo(a.as_ref().or(b.as_ref()))`? Won't that make an `Option<&T>`? How do I turn the `Option<&T>` back into an `&Option<T>` so I can pass it to `foo`?

Comment: You can't turn an `Option<&T>` to `&Option<T>` for free.

Comment: What's the best way to do it not for free?

Answer (score 6):

`&Option<T>` is almost never a useful type, but it can be [converted to `Option<&T>` using `as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref).

This means the following code works:

```rust
fn foo(f: Option<&Huge>) {}

fn bar(a: Option<&Huge>, b: Option<&Huge>) {
    foo(a.or(b));
}
```

Comment: Right but you've just changed the problem. How do I modify the line `foo()` without changing the rest of the code?

Comment: Yes, I intended to also change `foo` because it also uses `&Option<T>`.

Comment: @Timmmm You probably *should* change the rest of the code, because `&Option<T>` is strictly less general than `Option<&T>`. But if you insist on preserving the signature of `foo`, you have no options other than writing a `match` or an `if` like you mentioned in the question.